# Using SQL in PHP Results in Error PDO Statement

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to use the following script in PHP to get a name into a variable:

```
$fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,";")
$prod_no = " SELECT no FROM e_produit WHERE nom LIKE ".$fileop[0]." ";
$stmt = $pdo->query($prod_no);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row;
```

But all I get in the page is the following error:

> ERROR PDO Statement => errorCode=' SELECT no FROM e_produit WHERE nom LIKE NAVIGATOR 80G ' | error info =array ( 0 => '42000', 1 => 1064, 2 => 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'80G\' at line 1', ) in C:\wamp\www\ma-fourniture\liens\pdo2.php on line 64"

Comment: so what's wrong with this code? You're defining a string, and this code should do the trick. If you mean why you don't get any results from the database, well, you're not EXECUTING your query. You're just defining a string that happens to contain some sql.

Comment: You need to connect to a database and pass this query to it before you'll get results.

Comment: maybe posting the code for the entire page would help?

Comment: `nom` should also be quoted as its a string and are you sure you want `LIKE` and not `=`

Comment: Thankx for your answers. In fact, I have executed the script by: $pdo->query($prod_no); But I get the message: You have an error in your SQL syntax.

Comment: ^ Why not echo the statement and then try it in your database directly, e.g. via phpMyAdmin? That will show you what is going wrong (and read @Dagon's comment above).

Comment: well if you said that in the first place you would of waisted a lot less of every ones time

Comment: Sorry to waste your precious time.. I've tried to quote nom, It doesn't work. nom is the name of a column of my table

Comment: @YassineCesc: if you have updated your code, please also update your question, so we can see its new state.

Comment: Why are you printing `$prod_no` (the query string) rather than `$row`?

Comment: I've changed the code again. Now it makes more sense to me. The problem that I recieve is: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string".

Comment: You _still_ have an error in your SQL. Did you say `nom` is the name of a column? If so, maybe you meant to use `nom LIKE '%{$fileop[0]}%'`? To use the `LIKE` operator you have to use the format `<column> LIKE '<string>'` (adding `%` wildcards as appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a DB connection and execute your query, like

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=YOUR_HOSTNAME;dbname=YOUR_DBNAME;charset=utf8', 'YOUR_DB_USERNAME', 'YOUR_DB_PASSWORD');

$prod_no = " SELECT no FROM e_produit WHERE ".$fileop[0]." LIKE nom ";

$stmt = $db->query($prod_no);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

look at [php PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php)

Answer (score -1):

You are not doing any sort of query at all.  You are only assigning the query string to a variable.  This is what you need:

```
list($prod_no) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query(" SELECT no FROM e_produit WHERE ".$fileop[0]." LIKE nom "));
```

However, this is using just MySQL, assuming that is what you are using.  If you do not know how to use MySQL with PHP, you need to do tutorials.

Comment: I don't recommend nesting MySQL calls, since they each need to be checked for success/fail before continuing. Furthermore, this library is now deprecated, so answers here should not generally recommend it.

Comment: I agree with the deprecation, but since they don't specify what they are using, and the fact that they didn't know how to make the call initially, I assume they are trying to use this method.  Though as for the nesting, I don't really see an issue with it.  It will still give an error which can be checked if it fails, etc.

Comment: `mysql_query` will return `false` if there is a query error, and `mysql_fetch_array` requires a resource as its first parameter. Hence the nesting specifically prevents the output of `mysql_query` from being tested before the outer function is called. The error that will result is a really common question on Stack Overflow.